# AWS S3 is not connecting with API Gateway due to CORS errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I'm hosting my react application's build on S3 bucket, and I also have a lambda function running for my API using AWS's API-Gateway.
I'm trying to send a post/get requests from my static website to this API gateway (which is also using API KEY to authorize) and I'm getting CORS error for no reason.
I've tried to debug it using postman and everything works great.
I've added x-api-key to the default headers of axios in my application and inserted the key as requested.
Is there a problem using S3 for hosting a static website that uses POST/GET requests?

btw: I've allowed CORS in my API-gateway (as I said, it works on Postman)
Thanks!

Comment: Postman won't enforce CORS, it's a browser security technology, so that's not a good test in this case. Your browser's developer tools are where you need to look.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I am using python in lambda. Adding thiscode at the end solved my issue: return { 'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps('Success!') } ...